Can we open the "How to buy BTC" question?
How do you obtain bitcoins?
This was closed because:

This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only
  relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
  extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
  the worldwide audience of the internet.

I don't understand the reason for its closure, I don't think the above text is correct. I've already voted once to reopen it.

Voted to reopen - I think the author's comment is right on the mark: "It's not even dynamic: you can obtain bitcoins by charging, changing (just like any currency) or mining"

Reading the comments, HedgeMage closed it for two reasons. One was that it is too localized (in time) and the other was that it is too basic. I know that we have a lot of other questions that are just as localized and just as basic as this one so I agree with reopening it.
I think that it is important though that the answers should not just be a list of popular exchanges but rather an explanation of different ways to get bitcoins, where exchanges would be one of them. If the answer is written in a good way it doesn't have to change that much over time.
The community should decide what to do with it so I won't reopen it until I get some feedback though.

Are 6 votes enough cause to open?

@ripper234: I've reopened it now and made a comment linking back to this discussion.

until finally, congratulations
